# Is there a both manifestly covariant and unitary formalism of Quantum Field Theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, covariance, unitarity, quantization

The Lagrangian formalism is only manifestly covariant and the Hamiltonian formalism is only manifestly unitary.

In classical field theory, there exists the [De Donder Weyl formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Donder%E2%80%93Weyl_theory), which is Hamiltonian mechanics but done in a covariant way. Is there some De Donder quantisation which gives a manifestly unitary and covariant Quantum Field Theory?

The classical De Donder formalism has five state variables: one field strength and four field momenta (as opposed to an infinite number of state variables in the Hamiltonian formulation of classical field theory). If we promote these 5 variables to five operators on a Hilbert space, can we get a new formulation of Quantum Field Theory?

I'm not sure how one can get four different field momentum operators that are all canonically conjugate to the same field strength operator. Maybe one could start with the phase space formulation, by deforming the Poisson bracket of De Donder into  Moyal bracket. From there, one could get a Hilbert space formulation.

Comment: More on [De Donder Weyl theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=donder+weyl).

Comment: What about the path integral formalism is not covariant/unitary?

Comment: @ACuriousMind It's not manifestly unitary